# Angular 6 not working in IE11 and throw SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.js

Tags: angular, angular6

Im running an Angular 6 with .netCore webapi app and im trying to load it in IE11 
and its throw an error: 
"SCRIPT1002: Syntax error "
"vendor.js "

and show a blank page.

in chrome and edge it is working fine

I have already tried to uncomment polyfills, seek for packages that not build well in IE, tried to upgrade my angular cli. 
and added 
    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >`
in index.html

this is the package.json:

```
    "name": "stars",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node cli dev",
    "dev": "node cli dev",
    "prod": "node cli prod",
    "backend": "node cli runBackend",
    "client": "node cli runClient"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "build-utils": "^1.0.120",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "colors": "^1.3.1",
    "complog": "2.0.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "into-stream": "^3.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "object.values": "1.0.4",
    "opener": "^1.4.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "swiper": "^4.4.2",
    "t-rex": "^2.10.4",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.0.0-rc1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
}
```

I expect that the project will run in IE11 and below but the actual result that is not.

Comment: The error will point you to exact location in `vendor.js` code. Check the error line and search for polyfills for that erroneous statement. A lot of times we require new polyfills to render angular in IE11.

Comment: it points me to dom7 , i think dom7 related to swiper

Comment: can you post the exact error line? This may help you: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2282

Comment: It solve mt problem when i removed swiper . now i have to figure it out how to use swiper :) thank you

Comment: @B.k found anything?

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because swiper.
swiper.js uses Dom7, and dom 7 couses the problem 
so insted of using swiper like this :

```
import Swiper from 'swiper'
```

i used it like this:

```
import Swiper from '../../../../node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js';
```

i hope its helpful.